# jQuery DataTables() returns empty array, destroy() cannot be called on undefined.

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have the following code:

```
function clearAllCourses() {
    activeCourseIDs = [ 0 ];
    UnloadStudents();
    $('#Australia').show();
}

function UnloadStudents() {
        var table = $('#studentDrillDownDataTable');
        table.hide();
        table.DataTable().destroy();
        //table.clear().draw();
        //table.ajax.reload();
}
```

In my application, there's a dropdown menu that selects courses to be loaded into a table using jQuery DataTables. When the number of courses selected changes from some number of courses to no courses (zero), the `clearAllCourses()` function above is called, which in turn calls the `UnloadStudents()` function.

The problem occurs when `destroy()` is called on selected table object. Here are the errors, along with some output from Chrome Dev Tools' console to aid in debugging.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined jquery.dataTables.js:2574`

The error above occurs when any number of selected courses in the dropdown changes to no courses (zero) selected. The error implies that `table.DataTable()` returns `undefined` which in fact, returns an empty array (see below).

```
> $('#studentDrillDownDataTable').DataTable();
> []
```

As a result, `destroy()` does not execute properly, and so when any course is re-selected in the dropdown, this error occurs:

```
Uncaught Error: DataTables warning: table id=studentDrillDownDataTable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3 jquery.dataTables.js:4832
```

The next thought might be if `table` is not an initialized `DataTable` or if `table` is not what it should be. I have ruled this out, because here is the output when I select the table:

```
[<table class=​"table table-datatable table-custom display dataTable" id=​"studentDrillDownDataTable" width=​"100%" aria-describedby=​"studentDrillDownDataTable_info" role=​"grid" style=​"display:​ none;​ width:​ 100%;​">​…​</table>​]
```

Any idea what is going on and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you provide [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with full example?

Comment: jQuery DataTables is a pretty big library, and since I was just handed this huge JS app (someone else built it), I wouldn't know which pieces to grab and throw in the fiddle. Wish I could easily.

Comment: Without full example to debug, the only hope is for people who know `DataTables` well...

Comment: Maybe just put a wrapper on it, just in case?
$(table.DataTable()).destroy();

Comment: Tried the wrapper as you suggested, got some slightly different behavior, but still the error mentioned above about DataTables not being able to reinitialize the `DataTable`.

Answer (score 2):

Try $('#..').DataTable() change to $('#..').dataTable() - this is true for versions of DT > 1.9

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `destroy()`, it's bogus and does not work the way you want it to work. To destroy and reload a table manually, consider this approach

```
var dataSet = [];

if ($.fn.dataTable.isDataTable('#yourTable')) {
    $('#yourTable').DataTable({
        "destroy": true,
        "processing": true,
        "data": dataSet
    });
} else {
    $('#yourTable').DataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "data": dataSet
    });
}
```

If you don't have dynamic data, remove "data" property from both.

Comment: Since this data is dynamic and comes from `"ajax"` in the original initialization, should `"data"` here in this case be replaced with the `"ajax"` property?

Comment: I haven't worked a lot with ajax in conjunction with DataTables, but you can certainly give that a try. If performance is not a issue or the dataset will never be large, you can move the ajax response into an array then display it [If a straight ajax call does not work].